# Returning multiple values in a CASE expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have an outdated stored procedure that looks something like:

```
CASE
      WHEN (org.org_misc_data = 'PAC') THEN 'pac'
      WHEN (org.dues_category = 'PART') THEN 'partner_member'
      WHEN (org.dues_category = 'FREE' AND org.org_status_flag = 'P') THEN 'associate_member'
      ELSE 'non_member'
END AS org_status
```

The way it it currently written, as soon as it hits the first `WHEN` clause, my `org_status` value would be "pac". Can someone direct me how to re-write this so that `org_status` can contain return multiple values (ie: "pac|partner_member").

Comment: What's wrong in this one? it's doing correct only ... CASE will be evaluated for every row and obhiously any row can have only one type at max.

Comment: @Rahul ... OP wants to concatenate values based on varying conditions and criteria.

Comment: @swasheck, not sure; it's bit confusing to me ... I think he is asking that all the conditions are not checked or something like that.

Comment: CASE is an expression that returns a single value. It is not a switch statement or to be used for control of flow.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I know. This is why I am asking for alternative solutions to update this dated query based on new requests.

Comment: OK, I've edited the title of the question then, because it implied that a "switch statement" and a "CASE expression" were equivalent.

Comment: Why not add a second column using its own case statement rather than forcing a concatenated string into one column?  pac|partner_member is not an org_status.  It's like an org_status, and a business_relationship or something, it's two columns with two meanings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just using two `CASE` expressions?

```
CASE
  WHEN (org.org_misc_data = 'PAC') THEN 'pac|' ELSE '' END
  + CASE 
    WHEN (org.dues_category = 'PART') THEN 'partner_member'
    WHEN (org.dues_category = 'FREE' AND org.org_status_flag = 'P') THEN 'associate_member'
    ELSE 'non_member'
END AS org_status
```

It's tough to give a definitive answer because you haven't really outlined all of the possible permutations.

Comment: I didn't think of concatenating the `CASE` expressions. So in my case, if a user could be all three of returning values (pac, partner_member, and associate_member), I would have to concatenate all of the `CASE` expressions together?

Comment: They can't possibly be both partner_member and associate_member - they have to be one or the other, since they require different values in a single column (dues_category). Could you show some sample data and desired results for all possible combinations please? Reverse engineering your schema based on vague word problems is not my idea of a party. :-)

Comment: Also, is it possible to be a "pac" and a "non_member" or are these mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, that would be so nice.  SQL doesn't support multiple returns from a case.

If you are not adverse to string manipulation, you could do something like:

```
select *,
       left(org_status_letter, charindex('|', org_status_letter) - 1) as org_status,
       substring(org_status_letter, charindex('|', org_status_letter) + 1, 1000) as letter
from (select (CASE WHEN (org.org_misc_data = 'PAC') THEN 'pac|a'
                   WHEN (org.dues_category = 'PART') THEN 'partner_member|b'
                   ...
                   ELSE 'non_member'
              END) AS org_status_letter
```

A more intense solution would involve a lookup table.  So, your case statement would produce a unique key.  This key would then be joined to a lookup table and you could have as many values as you like.  However, this works for constants, but not for formulas.

Answer (score 0):

I think rather than combining the values and then breaking them back out later, it is better to always keep them separate.

```
CASE
      WHEN (org.org_misc_data = 'PAC') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsPack,
CASE     
      WHEN (org.dues_category = 'PART') THEN 'partner'
      WHEN (org.dues_category = 'FREE' 
                  AND org.org_status_flag = 'P') THEN 'associate'
      ELSE 'non' END AS MemberStatus
END AS org_status
```

Answer (score -1):

You can start AND'ing the conditions and returning the respective values...

```
CASE
    WHEN (org.org_misc_data = 'PAC' AND org.dues_category = 'PART') THEN 'pac|partner_member'
    ....
END AS org_status
```

Comment: How will that make any difference?

Comment: I am just saying...; that is one way to consolidate the values in the status variable, although it could potentially result in an unwieldy CASE clause in the query, since it would need to factor in every possible (that are relevant, of course) combination.